# Check url for string and 301 redirect to url without the string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have checked a lot of htaccess redirects but I can't seem to find one that suits my needs. We have an old url like this:

www.domain.com/shoes/nike/filter/gender/men

I would like a rule that checks the url for the string 'filter' and 301 redirects it to:

www.domain.com/shoes/nike

Is that possible with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/filter http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It simply deletes everything after "filter"